# dataimport, write different query result to same field

Tags: solr

in a dataimport (from mysql/jdbc) is it possible to have several entities writing the result to the same field?

if the destination field is a multivalue Int, what is the behaviour? the values will be appended?

```
<entity name="query1" query=".....">
    <field column="result1" name="my_field_is" />
</entity>

<entity name="query2" query=".....">
    <field column="result2" name="my_field_is" />
</entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put both queries in a single one using a [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), and "AS" if necessary. Then  you can use a single entity. Probably there are other options, but this one is the simplest I think.

Comment: actually i'm already using a `UNION` query, but it has become huge and difficult to mantain, so the decision to split is just for readability and maintain.
i think i'm going to split the query and then use `copyField` to have values in a single field